# Распознавание эмоций у детей нейронной сетью, натренированной шаблонами эмоций взрослых людей

Tags: нейронные-сети

Есть задача - создать модуль распознавания эмоций детей от 3 до 5 лет средствами нейронной сети, но нигде нет шаблонов именно детских лиц с различными эмоциями, только взрослые лица, поэтому возник вопрос: приемлимо ли тренировать подобную нейронную сеть шаблонами взрослых лиц и на сколько будет отличаться точность распознавания эмоций у детей?

Comment: не попробовав не узнаешь... Но мне кажется что эмоции у трехлетних детей могут существенно отличаться от эмоций взрослого человека.

Comment: Очередной вопрос, который отчетливо демонстрирует, почему Маск (и ряд других известных людей) предупреждают об опасности ИИ (в свете современного тренда использования нейросетей для его построения)